# Extract content of div tag except other tags using BeuatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have below HTML content, wherein div tag looks like below

```
<div class="block">aaa
 <p> bbb</p>
 <p> ccc</p>
</div>
```

From above I want to extract text only as "aaa" and not other tags content.

When I do,

```
 soup.find('div', {"class": "block"})
```

it gives me all the content as text and I want to avoid the contents of p tag.

Is there a method available in BeautifulSoup to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type of element,You could try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import element

s = '''
<div class="block">aaa
 <p> bbb</p>
 <p> ccc</p>
 <h1>ddd</h1>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")
for e in soup.find('div', {"class": "block"}):
    if type(e) == element.NavigableString and e.strip():
        print(e.strip())
# aaa
```

And this will ignore all text in sub tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `p` tags from that `div`, which effectively gives you the `aaa` text.

Here's how:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """<div class="block">aaa
 <p> bbb</p>
 <p> ccc</p>
</div>
"""

s = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser")
excluded = [i.extract() for i in s.find("div", class_="block").find_all("p")]
print(s.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_next()`, which returns the first match found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="block">aaa
 <p> bbb</p>
 <p> ccc</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.find('div', {"class": "block"}).find_next(text=True))
```

Output:

```
aaa
```